# Changes in PHP code not effective in IE8?

Tags: php, wordpress, firefox, internet-explorer-8

So I have this Wordpress (PHP) site (http://aesyliften.bwagnerdev.com) that I made some basic changes to in the site header (something that Wordpress adds to every single page), and the changes are reflected in Firefox 8, but in IE8, its the "old" (and broken) code...

What gives?

Comment: Try Ctrl+F5 in IE on your page.

Comment: @HonusWagner can you post the code t hat is not being updated?

Comment: @JonathonG The code would be a bit tricky to paste. I've made a more basic change to validate: I created a new PHP variable called `$true = true;`. Later in the page, I said `if ($true) { echo "TRUE"; } else { echo "FALSE"; }`. Neither piece of text shows up in the source after full browser cache clear and refresh. I even took it a step further and **DELETED A BUNCH OF CODE** and still the effects of that code are showing up in IE8.

Comment: so nothing changes on the page, regardless of what the changes are?

Comment: @HonusWagner can you post a link to the page I should look for the change on, and tell me what to look for? If I can't see it, that removes the chance of it being a client side issue by 100%. If I CAN see it then the only problem is your browser, no one elses.

Comment: @JonathonG Thats right. I DELETED a bunch of code, and pulled it up on a different computer that has never been to that site before, and I still am not seeing the changes.

Comment: Well I'm afraid I've run out of ideas... this is too bizarre.

Comment: Woah..... now its working just fine.... no changes.....

Answer (score 5):

It could very well be cached. IE is notorious for caching things when no other browser does. You could try clearing your IE8 cache.

**EDIT:** IE8 can be seriously stubborn about clearing that cache. Make sure you've checked to clear EVERYTHING. That still might not work. Have you put this in your header?

```
<?php
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate"); // HTTP/1.1
header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT"); // Date in the past
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you clear your IE cache?

`Tools > Internet Options > General > Browsing History > Delete.`

Comment: Are you certain that IE is loading old code, not not simply rending new code incorrectly? Can you actually see the new code when you do view source?

Comment: I just put in the page `echo "***TEST***"`. In FF it shows up. In IE8, it does not.

Comment: What if you upload a new file into the root, say "test.txt". If you go to it with IE, do you get the file, or 404?

Comment: Did that, and I got the file in IE8. What did that prove exactly?

Comment: Are you using a load balancer or CDN of any sort?

Comment: I'm not sure what a CDN is. My host is HostGator if that makes a difference?

Comment: Are you personally behind a proxy or VPN? Does IE on another computer on another network render it correctly?

Comment: No and no. I just pulled it up on another computer (my wife's). That computer has NEVER been to that site (definitely) and it pulled up incorrectly.... now I'm really confused.